# help with pfiles output

Tags: java, solaris

I deployed my application on a Weblogic 10.3 which is installed on a solaris. After a while I began to see "Too many open files" exceptions which yields to numerious problems. I took a pfiles output and nearly all the output is filled with lines which are similar to these:

```
1489: S_IFCHR mode:0000 dev:299,0 ino:51621 uid:0 gid:0 rdev:202,1966
  O_RDWR
  /devices/pci@7c0/pci@0/network@4:bge0
1490: S_IFCHR mode:0000 dev:299,0 ino:51619 uid:0 gid:0 rdev:202,1967
  O_RDWR
  /devices/pci@7c0/pci@0/network@4:bge0
1491: S_IFCHR mode:0000 dev:299,0 ino:53648 uid:0 gid:0 rdev:202,1968
  O_RDWR
  /devices/pci@7c0/pci@0/network@4:bge0
1492: S_IFCHR mode:0000 dev:299,0 ino:51618 uid:0 gid:0 rdev:202,1969
  O_RDWR
  /devices/pci@7c0/pci@0/network@4:bge0
1493: S_IFCHR mode:0000 dev:299,0 ino:51617 uid:0 gid:0 rdev:202,1970
  O_RDWR
  /devices/pci@7c0/pci@0/network@4:bge0
1494: S_IFCHR mode:0000 dev:299,0 ino:51616 uid:0 gid:0 rdev:202,1971
  O_RDWR
  /devices/pci@7c0/pci@0/network@4:bge0
1495: S_IFCHR mode:0000 dev:299,0 ino:39102 uid:0 gid:0 rdev:202,1972
  O_RDWR
  /devices/pci@7c0/pci@0/network@4:bge0
```

Do you have any idea what these lines are trying to tell us?

Note: As requested in comments, I added "ls -li /devices/pci@7c0/pci@0/network@4:bge0" output below:

```
# ls -li /devices/pci@7c0/pci@0/network@4:bge0 
105906182 crw-rw-rw- 1 root sys 202, 1 Jul 1 09:34 /devices/pci@7c0/pci@0/network@4:bge0 
# ls -li /devices/pci@7c0/pci@0/network@4:bge0 
105906182 crw-rw-rw- 1 root sys 202, 1 Jul 1 09:34 /devices/pci@7c0/pci@0/network@4:bge0 
# ls -li /devices/pci@7c0/pci@0/network@4:bge0 
105906182 crw-rw-rw- 1 root sys 202, 1 Jul 1 09:34 /devices/pci@7c0/pci@0/network@4:bge0
```

Comment: What says `ls -li /devices/pci@7c0/pci@0/network@4:bge0` ?
Does its inode number change over the time ?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by that. How can I understand whether its inode number changes over the time?

Comment: # ls -li /devices/pci@7c0/pci@0/network@4:bge0 
 105906182 crw-rw-rw-   1 root     sys      202,  1 Jul  1 09:34 /devices/pci@7c0/pci@0/network@4:bge0
# ls -li /devices/pci@7c0/pci@0/network@4:bge0 
 105906182 crw-rw-rw-   1 root     sys      202,  1 Jul  1 09:34 /devices/pci@7c0/pci@0/network@4:bge0
# ls -li /devices/pci@7c0/pci@0/network@4:bge0 
 105906182 crw-rw-rw-   1 root     sys      202,  1 Jul  1 09:34 /devices/pci@7c0/pci@0/network@4:bge0

Comment: Please post this information in your initial question, not as a comment where it lacks formatting. In any case, what you just posted doesn't look to come from the same machine pfiles was run.

Comment: I edited the question, sorry about that. Why did you said that it doesn't look to come from the same machine. It *is* from the same server :)

Comment: Because neither the inode numbers (105906182 vs 1489+) nor the device ones (202,1 vs 202,1966+) match. I would say there is an issue around your nic. Did you look at your system logs for messages about the bge driver ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your application is opening sockets that it never closes.  Check your app.